# How do you remove hair from around your anus

Tags: hair, fitrah

The scholars state it is recommended to do this as filth can attach to the hair and it is included in the definition of pubic hair. Now I don't wish to use a razor but just a trim - looking in a mirror underneath and small scissors is very hard. If you are unmarried or the wife doesn't want to assist what can you do? Only a doctor if he is examining that area may see it without it being haraam. What other options are available? I can't think of any more.

Comment: You could use then men hair removal creams instead.

Comment: Hair removal cream on sensitive skin in the pubic region has a good chance of giving you chemical burns. Maybe ask someone who knows about those products (a beautician or someone in a waxing studio) about possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience. 
At young ages when the hair start to appear I used to use a small scissors but that would take long time and sometimes you may hurt yourself. After that one my friends said he used a razor so I tried it with caution I used to use the fix blades which are not flexibility nowadays I used one of Gillette razors with flexible blades they are very good because it somehow does not hurt the skin When I was young that was easy because no belly there hehe but now it is harder with my belly. If you have a big enough mirror in the bath room that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy. Use disposable razor (eg gilette) and any sensitve shaving cream (eg nivea). Place foot onto high place (bath tub edge/sink surface) to access under carriage. Hold razor in thumb and first finger. Run strokes towards groove/crack starting with butt cheek of the leg on the floor. Repeat otherside. Gentle slide of razor is totally safe with safety razor. 
The scrotum (ball sack) should be done first. Just pull the skin so it is stretched and gentle strokes will clean pubic hair. DO NOT USE MACHINES OR SCISSORS.

Answer (score -1):

If you are unmarried or the wife is unwilling to help, and removal creams are out of the question, then I suggest that using a mirror and a small scissor is the best way to cut the hair, and then using a razor to shave the shorter hairs after the longer ones have already been cut with the scissors.

Answer (score -4):

it's quite a shame that even now in 2018 men arent taught about self grooming properly, there's 3 ways I absolutely recommend trimming the hair around the anus, cheeks, testicles and even penis, please read;

1. Yes it's possible to shave and it can be safe IF you use aloe vera based shave gel, and a standard disposable razor (don't use the brand BIC) test the gel on your skin first so you're aware if it irritates or not, then apply the gel on the pubic areas and short gentle strokes, I promise if you do this correctly it will not cut you, finish off by rinsing with cool water, dry and then apply shave balm followed by talc powder if possible.
2. yes it's also possible to trim as long as you do NOT expose the teeth of the blade of your trimmer directly on your skin and especially around the testicles region, use a guard preferably grade 0.5 to grade 1, rinse with cool water and dry.
3. This to be honest is the best way you can now buy hair removal cream for men and no it's not feminine to use dont feel embarrassed or ashamed, do a patch test on your arm or leg first to see how it reacts, if all is good then apply on your pubic area leave for roughly 3-5 mins if you feel it stinging slightly then wash off with cold water straight away, do the same once times up, then dry gently and finish off the same way in number 1.

thank me later brothers.